# Does Orbitz.com provide commercial APIs for integration?

Tags: api

I'm interested to know if Orbitz.com provides any commercial APIs to integration with their services. Anyone has related information?

So far, not much info mentioned in Orbitz.com.

Comment: Seems like http://corp.orbitz.com/partnerships/affiliates would be a start.

Answer (score 0):

Expedia, the parent company of orbitz.com, has APIs available for the following:

- Car Search
- Cruise APIs
- Flight Search
- Flights Overview
- Geography Search
- Hotel Reviews
- Hotel Review Analyzer
- Hotel Search, Offers, and Info
- Media Search
- Natural Language Hotel Search
- Package Search
- Suggestions and Resolutions API
- Travel Content Service (TCS)
- Things to do
- Travel Trends
- Unreal Deals

There is also a private label API for hotel booking which offers the following features:

- Hotel List
- Hotel Information
- Room Images
- Room Availability
- Payment Types
- Book Reservation
- View Itinerary
- Cancel Itinerary
- Resume Reservation

**References**

- [Expedia API Documentation | Public APIs](https://hackathon.expedia.com/docs/public/api/)
- [SOAP to REST Update Guide — EAN Developer Site](http://developer.ean.com/docs/rest-update)

Comment: @MaksymPolshcha The URL is up. Best to report the search engine issue with [Yahoo Pipes](https://developer.yahoo.com/forums/#/categories/yahoo-pipes).